# How to compile and install LLVM 13 from source on windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, clang, llvm

I want to install LLVM 13.0.1 in my local windows (64 bit)  system to use it for creating a working enviorment for open source project. I downloaded and install from [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-13.0.1)  but I found it is not complete It is missing many library files and cmake files  that are required and getting errors while building. so I want now to install LLVM 13.0.1 from source.
I am very early in  learning LLVM , Clang so don't have any idea of doing so. Can anyone give me the entire step / commands to do so.

Comment: The complete instructions are on their web site, so you must have done something wrong. I went though the process a few years ago. it's complicated and you need a powerful PC, but it is possible.

Comment: The instructions are [here](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html). They recommend using git to obtain the source, but downloading it separately is also possible.

Comment: LLVM for Windows assumes that you already have Microsoft's libraries installed, and tries to use those. Don't know if "building from source" changes this. Also, is 13.0.1 particularly better than versions 14 or 15?